# Is it wrong to write 'It is enough'

Tags: grammar

from English Grammar in Use 5th Edition, page 206

1.'Enough' goes after adverbs and adjectives

2.'Enough' normally goes before nouns

3.We also use 'enough' alone

But I think I heard 'It is enough!' before, many times. So, enough comes after a verb here. But the book doesn't mention this situation. Is it wrong (especially in formal writing, namely in an academic paper.) to write 'It is enough.'

Comment: The expression **It is enough** is common and perfectly correct, as you can easily confirm by googling it. The word **enough** goes in lots of places that your book doesn't mention. Enough has now been said on this matter.

Comment: @RonaldSole Thanks Ronald, I don't understand why the book limits the topic. It wouldn't be a great effort to add one sentence and say 'We also use enough in lots of situations.' Sure, a grammar book can't include all of the aspects. On the other hand, the author/authors can simply underline that 'There are other usages that we didn't include, such as...'

Comment: Regrettably,  a great many writers of grammar books would be better off reading them.

Comment: It depends what it means by "alone". It's possible that in "*It is enough*", "enough" is alone in the sense that it makes up the entire subject complement.

Comment: Need more context to determine whether it would be appropriate in your article. What does "it" refer to? What is the general point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It is enough" (or "*that* is enough") is perfectly idiomatic.

You are right that 'enough' can go before a noun, for example "*enough water*". But the word '**it**' refers to something previously stated or immediately obvious to the audience, and removes the need to constantly restate the noun subject. If, for example, someone was pouring water into a glass you wouldn't need to say "*that is enough water*" because it is obvious what you are referring to. It is enough to say "*that's enough*"!

Answer (score 0):

Please be careful:

A **general statement** may begin with:
*It's enough* to wash that car before driving it.
It's enough to pay for the dinner. You don't need to do anything else.

**Enough** of the money was spent to help the poor lady down the block. [noun]
**Enough money** was spent to help etc. [adjective]
**Enough is enough**. Stop making all that racket. [nouns]

COMPARE: **That's** enough. Don't use any more flour in that cake.

I recommend the British Council site to fully review this and the test at the end. I didn't want to copy the entire thing.

[Enough via the British Council site](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/enough#:%7E:text=enough%20means%20%27as%20much%20as,also%20act%20as%20a%20pronoun.)
Grammar explanation
enough means 'as much as necessary'. **It can be used with an adjective, an adverb, a verb or a noun. It can also act as a pronoun.**